# If I have an iPod touch (1st gen) can I install apps?

Tags: ios, ipod-touch, ios-appstore

I found what I think is a first gen iPod touch ([see here](https://selfsolve.apple.com/RegisterProduct.do?productRegister=Y&country=USA&id=1B74210FW4T)).

I had to restore it and it says it cannot update beyond iOS 2.2.1, build version 5H11.

When I browse the App Store, all apps seem to require a minimum of iOS 4.3.

- Can I upgrade iOS beyond 2.2.1?
- Can I install apps?
- Where can I browse for compatible apps?

Answer (score 2):

You can update an ipod touch 1G up to ios 3.1.3.  Finding available apps that work on ios 3.1.3 or earlier can be painstakingly hard using the Apple app store.  An app store app called "VintApps" makes this super easy.

https://www.facebook.com/VintApps313

Answer (score 1):

After you upgrade to iOS 3.1.3 you can use this tool to search the iTunes store for apps that are compatible with the 1st generation iPod Touch. It's easier on a desktop computer. Select iPhone (original) from the menu.

See: [**iOSSearch: Find games and apps for 1st, 2nd generation iPod Touch,iPhone 3G, iOS 4.2.1 & 3.1.3**](https://sites.google.com/site/iossearch/)

This is a non-commercial page I made.

Answer (score 0):

the las build support for the iPod touch 1G - 1.1.5 (4B1) (Free) iOS 3.1.3 (7E18) (Paid)

so you should be able to upgrade sense you already have 2.2.1

next regarding your need for the latest iOS to install certain apps, im afraid you are out of luck, see the API these apps use require a later os, usually 4.X cause of the multitask and so on

Solution: [Whited00r](http://www.whited00r.com)

Comment: it will work great, i did it on a ituch1g last week, however don compare the speed to a new iPhone or anything!

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I restored to the 3.1.3 (7E18) and then tried to install and I always get error 1604 and the forums don't seem to really solve it :(

Comment: put it in DFU and and restore it with Whited00r the errors do occur, keep trying, and switch ports and just keep trying, took me like 30 times....

Answer (score 0):

1: You can upgrade to iOS 3.1.3, but I don't think Apple sells it anymore. After searching around, I found [this](http://pfd.apple.com/ProtectedAsset/iPodTouch/061-7479.20100202.Secrc/iPod1,1_3.1.3_7E18_Restore.ipsw?downloadKey=1363372516_3f19888698081358f834e85cb5c394f3), which is the iOS 3.1.3 IPSW for your iPod. It's on Apple's servers, so AFAIK it's legal. If you don't know how to install IPSWs, look [here](http://www.forum.shaarpmind.com/showthread.php/298944-How-To-Manually-install-and-restore-iPhone-iPad-iPod-IPSW-files).

2: You can install apps, as long as they support iOS 3.1.3. There are /some/ that still do. [whited00r](http://www.whited00r.com/iPodTouch1G) is themed to look like iOS 6, and works with your iPod touch, but more importantly, it has an app named the '3 Store' that lets you get old versions of apps that work for iOS 3.

Hopefully this helped.

Comment: I can't install whited00r. It doesn't seem to work. I restored to the 3.1.3 (7E18) and then tried to install and I always get error 1604 and the forums don't seem to really solve it :(

Comment: Try downgrading your iTunes - that helped for me. I believe iTunes 9.1 is the one that you want.
Also, make sure you're restoring in DFU mode.

Answer (score 0):

When installing whited00r to your iPod Touch, you need to downgrade your firmware from 3.1.3 to a lesser version. I found this after hours of trial and error. It will not happen with the latest 3.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

A change as of very recently allows you to browse the app store, and when you download an app if it is not compatible it will offer the chance to download the most recent version that *is* compatible (should there be one in existence).

[image]

Comment: Without guarantee that it will actually work though (e.g. WhatsApp which changed to protocol some time ago or any app which relies on a remote API).

Comment: Sure, it's more of a *Sorry, you can't run this, but you can TRY this older version*.  Games and such should be fine, anything that syncs or connects to other services or websites may be broken.

Answer (score -2):

download ios 3.1.3  apps from here http://apptimemachine.com/apple.html

Comment: The link you added doesn't appear to be working. Can you explain how it works today (as opposed to how it might work some day?)

Comment: The link appears to go to a fake Apple site and tries to get you to install a fake "flash player" app which does who knows what.